# More pythonic way to filter objects from a list of dicts based on a dict value that must not contain a string from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

As I'm coming from Java, I wonder if there is a more pythonic approach to achieve the following logic:

```
movies = [{'original_title': 'Star Wars'}, {'original_title': 'Avengers'}, {'original_title': 'After Love'}]
blacklist = ['Star', 'Love']

filtered_movies = []
for movie in movies:
    blacklisted = False
    for item in blacklist:
        if item in movie['original_title']:
            blacklisted = True
            break
    if not blacklisted:
        filtered_movies.append(movie)

return filtered_movies
```

`filtered_movies` then only contains the item `{'original_title': 'Avengers'}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
filtered_movies = [movie for movie in movies 
                   if not any(
                      item in movie['original_title']
                      for item in blacklist
                   )]
```

For example:

```
>>> movies = [{'original_title': 'Star Wars'}, {'original_title': 'Avengers'}, {'original_title': 'After Love'}]
>>> blacklist = ['Star', 'Love']
>>> filtered_movies = [movie for movie in movies
... if not any(item in movie['original_title'] for item in blacklist)]
>>> filtered_movies
[{'original_title': 'Avengers'}]
```

This is a pretty canonical way of performing this sort of filtering operation; the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) (used here) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) methods are particularly useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this, but no idea if this is a more pythonic approach.

```
movies = [
    {'original_title': 'Star Wars'},
    {'original_title': 'Avengers'},
    {'original_title': 'After Love'},
]
blacklist = ['Star', 'Love']

filtered_movies = []
for movie in movies:
    if any(word in movie['original_title'] for word in blacklist):
        continue
    filtered_movies.append(movie)

print(filtered_movies)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go  using filter and lambda function and set

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: len(set(blacklist) & set(x["original_title"].split())) == 0, movies))
[{'original_title': 'Avengers'}]
```

if splitting is not allowed then:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: len([1 for y in blacklist if y in x["original_title"]])==0, movies))
[{'original_title': 'Avengers'}]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not any(1 for y in blacklist if y in x["original_title"]), movies))
[{'original_title': 'Avengers'}]
```

Comment: OP never said anything about splitting into words or anything like that, so I assume this isn't going to work. For example, OP's code will filter `"Stardust"` and `"The Lovely Bones"`, but this won't.

Comment: Also, `list(filter(lambda))` can be more cleanly written as a list comprehension, like in [larsks's answer](/a/75050428/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea OP also haven't mentioned  not to split :)

Comment: @wjandrea I have updated if splitting on words is not allowed.

Comment: You can rewrite `any(1 for y in blacklist if y in x["original_title"])` more cleanly as `any(y in x["original_title"] for y in blacklist)`

Comment: @wjandrea I think that is fine it convey the same